# CSS Sprite not working - Edit this Fiddle

Tags: html, css, sprite

Who is a whiz with Sprites?

I updated the code today on a website, and must have made some changes to the CSS at some time in the past.

Now, the Sprite does not work when it is moused over like it should.

CSS:

```
.sprite {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-shadow:4px 4px 8px #696969;
  vertical-align: -10px;
}
.sprite span {
  top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.sprite a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/92jBDie.png') no-repeat fixed 0 -100px;
  color:Silver;
  display:block; 
  height:50px;
  width:150px;    
}
.sprite a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
  color:Red;
}
.sprite a:active {
  background-position: 0 0;        
  color:Black;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sprite"><a><span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="sprite"><a><span>2</span></a></li>
    <li class="sprite"><a><span>3</span></a></li>
    <li class="sprite"><a><span>4</span></a></li>
    <li class="sprite"><a><span>5</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/KEfhd/)

I've spent way too many hours trying to figure this out, today.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below

```
.sprite a {
      background: url('http://i.imgur.com/92jBDie.png') no-repeat fixed 0 -100px;
}
```

should be

```
.sprite a {
      background: url('http://i.imgur.com/92jBDie.png') no-repeat 0 -100px;
}
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/KEfhd/3/

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with sprites, the list and body are adding margins and paddings (by default).

Either implement a reset stylesheet or manually clear them as I did:

I've added

```
body, div, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And commented out `/*margin-top: 5px;*/` in `.sprite`

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KEfhd/2/

Comment: +1, but... These should all be the same. In yours, 1 and 2 act differently, and 3, 4 and 5 do nothing (like mine).